# Published .NET app is looking for API in source folder

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, iis-8.5

I'm new to API development and have created a Web API app that works fine locally (Visual Studio / IIS Express).  When I publish and deploy to IIS 8.5, the HTML pages work fine, but when I make an ajax call to my APIs, I get a 500 error. It somehow seems to be looking at my source code folder on my c: drive!, instead of the dll.

I'm guessing I botched something in the VS Publish setting, or in my API routing in WebApiConfig.

[image: Here's the call, ran from the IIS server]

Any idea on why it's looking in my source directory?

Comment: This is fine, no problem. It is not "looking" anywhere. It just shows you the stack trace, i.e. it tells you where the exception happened in terms of your source code. This is to help you to see in your source code the place of exception, and possibly debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand, is that your API is expecting custom header as part of your request. Please use PostMan or any other REST API Client to test your API by adding required headers. If you build and publish in release mode you will not find your local source code folder path.